# Combine/match two lists with different number of rows

Tags: excel

[image]

I need to pull data from column B and add for each row in column A to create Columns D/E.

I'm not sure the phrase to search a formula. I've searched different excel forums and I don't believe it's stacking or merging.

Is there a way to do this besides copy + paste? VBA perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that each row of column **A** repeats as many times as rows has the column **B** and the set of values from column **B** is repeated as many times as rows has the column **A**, therefore:

```
=LET(A,A1:A5, B,B1:B3, nA,ROWS(A), nB,ROWS(B), HSTACK(
 TOCOL(1*REPT(A, SEQUENCE(,nB,1,0))),TOCOL(REPT(B, SEQUENCE(,nA,1,0)),,1)))
```

If you don't want the result of the first column as numeric, then remove `1*` from the formula. You can use `INDEX` instead, to avoid any data transformation to text `REPT` does:

```
=LET(A,A1:A5, B,B1:B3, nA,ROWS(A), nB,ROWS(B), HSTACK(
 TOCOL(INDEX(A,SEQUENCE(nA),SEQUENCE(,nB,1,0))),
 TOCOL(INDEX(B,SEQUENCE(nB),SEQUENCE(,nA,1,0)),,1)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

**Note**: You can encapsulate common calculation in *both cases* in a user `LAMBDA` function (`Z`). For example this is the formula for the `INDEX` approach:

```
=LET(A,A1:A5,B,B1:B3,nA,ROWS(A),nB,ROWS(B), Z, LAMBDA(x,n,m,INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(n),
 SEQUENCE(,m,1,0))), HSTACK(TOCOL(Z(A,nA,nB)),TOCOL(Z(B,nB,nA),,1)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

The last solution worked. Saved me plenty of time and added something for me to learn.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This will work for any number of columns, as long as the number of resulting rows does not exceed the number of rows on the sheet.

```excel-formula
=LET(
    rng,A2:B6,
    rw,ROWS(rng),
    clm,COLUMNS(rng),
    s,SORT(MAKEARRAY(rw^clm,clm,LAMBDA(a,b,INDEX(rng,INT(MOD(a,rw^b)/(rw^b/rw))+1,b))),SEQUENCE(,clm))&"",
    FILTER(IF(ISNUMBER(--s),--s,s),MMULT(--(s=""),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(s),,1,0))=0))
```

[image]